# Java end of file

Tags: java, string, eof

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 1;
        
        while (line.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = line.nextLine();

            System.out.println(counter + " " + line);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Task: Each line will contain a non-empty string. Read until EOF.
For each line, print the line number followed by a single space and the line content.

Sample Input:

```
Hello world

I am a file

Read me until end-of-file.
```

Sample Output:

```
1 Hello world

2 I am a file

3 Read me until end-of-file.
```

Comment: Error : No suitable constructor found for scanner

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Also you are initializing counter variable inside loop.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to scan from a file, you can use the below code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        int counter = 1;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(counter + " " + line);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(); // <-- YOUR ERROR - there is no constructor for the Scanner object that takes 0 arguments. 
// You need to specify the environment in which you wish to 'scan'. Is it the IDE? A file? You need to specify that.
```

Since you said EOF, I'm assuming there is a File associated with this task.

Create a File object, toss that into the Scanner constructor.

```
File readFile = new File(PATH_TO_FILE); // where PATH_TO_FILE is the String path to the location of the file
// Set Scanner to readFile
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(readFile);
```

You also have a duplicate local variable named: line

I suggest you do more reading to get a grasp of how variables and objects work rather than guess or be spoonfed code you don't understand. That's how you become a strong programmer.

Answer (score 3):

[`Documentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) states that you need to pass `Source` to Scanner, so that it can scan from it.

To get user input then you need to use [`Scanner(InputStream source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29) constructor.

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in); // Added source parameter in constructor.
    int counter = 1; // Initialization of counter is done outside while loop, otherwise it will always get initialized by 1 in while loop
    while (line.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineStr = line.nextLine(); // changed variable name to lineStr, because 2 variable can't be declared with the same name in a method.
        System.out.println(counter + " " + lineStr);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you `break` your while loop, otherwise it will go into `infinite` loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't have multiple variable without the same name. You must rename one of your `line` variables.
2. When creating a scanner, you need to send in the input stream you want it to read from. System.in can server as this stream and it will read from your console. Your question though seems to indicate that you want to read from a file. If you indeed want to read from a file, you need to create the file you want to read from and send that file into the scanner to allow the scanner to read from that file.

Try:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create the File
        File file = new File(filename);

        //send the file into Scanner so it can read from the file
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        //initialize the counter variable
        int counter = 1;

        //read in the file line by line
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(counter  +" "+ line);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read user input, you need to use `System.in` in your declaration of the `line` object in your code:

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(System.in);
int counter = 0; // Initialized out of loop.
while (line.hasNextLine()) {
  String ln = line.nextLine();
  System.out.println(counter  +" "+ln);
  counter++;
}
```